# Need answer dashboard suddenly broke

Tags: bug, front-page

I just found that my filter no longer work:

[image: Broken tag filtering]

I have no idea what happened. The criteria is some common tags, and I surely selected [any]. It seems there's no longer a dropdown for "need answer". However, there are surely some leftover, since it shows "x new question available" and I can load them with a click.

Comment: Just tried it. It seems that if you select "all" once, it will go back to selecting "all" even when you tell it to use "any". Maybe something in the UI broke.

Comment: Lots of existing questions about this, type "that's a miss" in the Search box.  Won't be a miss :)

Comment: This sometimes happens, as the backend times out sometimes. Just reload the page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 1 hour elapsed, nothing changed.

Comment: Yup, some times it is worse than other times. The backend appears to be overloaded a little. Try removing one of your filters, that'll make the query lighter. Not always an acceptable work-around, but gives you *most* of what you want.